# What benefits are there to having a Pension (Retirement Account) In Ireland?

Tags: investing, pension, pension-plan, ireland

What benefits are there to having a retirement account called a "pension" in Ireland, as opposed to simply making investments of one kind or another for the same purpose? I am not really asking about the payback as such, more about the security and nature of the arrangement; in that I understand that a pension carries with it certain other benefits, for instance my financial advisor told me one thing about tax breaks based on pension payments and also something about an individual who went bankrupt and though his creditors were able to take his house and businesses, they couldn't by law touch his pension.

I am in Ireland so the law may be different per country, so I am really just asking generally, are there other benefits similar to these, or what is the difference between having bona fide pension and say if i was good at playing stock market or something like that?

I stared a pension recently and at the end of one year I had the exact same as what I put in, plus €4. Further to this while I believe that the pension I am on is with a good company, is there any guarantee that I wouldn't end up with less than I put in?

Comment: Please define what you mean by "pension". Is this a fund where you pay in and money is invested for you to take out on your retirement, or is this where you pay money on a regular basis and the company promises to pay you a fixed income when you retire?

Comment: @DJClayworth I've seen "pension" used this way for other questions from the UK, but I haven't gotten a clear answer on how a UK "pension" compares to a US 401k or US "pension".

Comment: @DJClayworth by pension I mean a fund where i pay money in and money is invested for me to take out on retirement

Comment: @Alex B ... other questions from the UK ? Ireland is not in the UK ;-) . I have no idea how they do things over there actually but we are often similar allright. The same term in Ireland governs whether an individual pays into a fund on their own or via their employer. There are differences in taxation maybe I think but ??

Comment: @byronyasgur - I meant another question which happened to be from the UK.   Just typing too fast :)

Comment: I probably should mention that I am self employed. Essentially this is an arrangement between me and my financial advisor/broker. We have selected a company who invest my money for me and pay it back later.

Comment: @byronyasgur In the US, Pension typically means defined benefit plan where a company commits to pay you some number of dollars in return for a lengthy career with a company.  They have gotten less and less common.   I think "pension" in this sense is equivalent to a US Retirement account.   In the US, the accounts are taxed different and have different contribution rules if it is a 401k, IRA, or Roth IRA.

Comment: Given above comments, I'm converting my answer to a comment: One of the biggest risks of a pension (as the term is used in the US) is that if your employer goes bankrupt the bankruptcy court can reduce the employer's future liability to you. Keep in mind that a pension is just a promise, and money is not yours until you have received it. A retirement account is yours and you can do what you want with it (including lose it all). With a retirement account, you control how safe or risky your funds are. With a pension plan, you have to trust someone else to do it for you.

Comment: @sheegaon With a retirement plan then; is it fair to say that even if i pick the safest options there is no actual guarantee (say in the face of a length global depression of stocks shares and currencies ) that it couldn't loose money. I mean to say there is no guarantee on anything really. If a company agrees to pay me money when I retire there is no guarantee that they're actually going to have any money, or is there ?

Comment: @byronyasgur not sure about Ireland, but in the US you can invest your retirement plan assets in a bank CD and then it is covered by the US government (FDIC) up to $250,000 per bank account (no limit on bank accounts an individual can open, just hassle).

Comment: @sheegaon - yes there is possibly something like that here too i will investigate. ( ps i didnt notice you were the same poster as below )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you point out, the main benefits of a pension/retirement account over a traditional cash/taxable account are the legal and tax benefits.  Most Western countries establish a specific legal definition for an account which is often taxed less or not at all relative to taxable accounts and which contains some protection for the owner in case of a bankruptcy.  The typical drawbacks for investing within such structures are limited investment choice, limited withdrawal rights (either in terms of age or rate of withdrawal), and maximum contributions.  The benefits are usually very clear, and your decision whether or not to open a pension/retirement account should depend on a careful weighing of the benefits and drawbacks.

As to whether you may end up with less than you started, that depends on what you invest in.  As with all of finance, you must take more risk to get more return.  Although the choices inside a pension/retirement account may be worded somewhat differently, they are usually fundamentally no different than some of the most popular investments available for ordinary taxable accounts.

Comment: thanks for the information - actually though it's _discontinuing_ my pension account that i'm considering - as opposed to opening up one. I dont really believe that the stocks shares and currencies that back the pensions funds are going to go anywhere but down over the next decade so i'm thinking of investing in physical gold and/or silver instead.

Comment: @byronyasgur There may be serious adverse tax consequences to such a move if you are relatively young.  Consider transferring the funds to another pension fund which allows more flexibility, such as investing in any stock, then you can own silver or gold (although I wouldn't recommend it) in ETF or other form.

Comment: Yes. I did think of that but the problem is that EFT silver and gold is not the same as physical there is no guarantee to it in the face of any kind of financial collapse, it's the same as stocks and shares or FIAT currency.

Comment: ... actually what type of tax consequences do you mean. I know that I wouldn't qualify for tax breaks on physical gold but it is exempt from VAT here.

Comment: @byronyasgur I'm talking about penalties on early withdrawal of pension assets.

Comment: I think that if the ETFs fail to make good on their guarantees (which are not actually flimsy guarantees but are a real trust backed by real metal in some cases), you will have bigger things to worry about than your pension plan.  I mean, in that case, you will have to worry about where to buy your food, since I'm assuming you buy most of your food rather than grow it yourself.  Seriously, it is not a realistic scenario.

Comment: Yes, you are right of course. I just dont want my pension to go to waste as well - it's one thing being concerned about where to buy food but not having money to buy it with is a bigger problem. PS i really dont think any of the ETFs are 100% actually backed by real metal, do you? Personally I wouldnt like to be in the queue looking for my measly few thousand IF the system did collapse. Notwithstanding all that there is no guarantee of course that anything is going to collapse at all so that's the purpose of my post here is to find out more about traditional ways of storing retirement funds.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an [Irish government publication](http://www.pensionsboard.ie/en/Publications/Information_Booklets/What_are_my_Pension_Options.pdf) that should give you some background information to get you started.

In a nutshell, you get tax benefits, but cannot withdraw money without penalty until you reach retirement age.